# WCF: Passing Kerboros token via HTTP call instead of HTTPS

Tags: wcf, http, https, kerberos

I want to pass Kerberos token via HTTP call to a server using WCF.

I have a piece of code that successfully does this. But it only works if I make a request to HTTPS URI.

```
var httpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue };
httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
httpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "MyCompany.com";

var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("https:xxxxxxxx.com/my/service);  // This works
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http:xxxxxxxx.com/my/service);   // This does not work

var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>(httpBinding, endPoint);
channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
_channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

_channel.ConsumeService();
```

If I make a request via the channel, and if the end point is https. It works and I can verify the Kerberos Token is in the HTTP requst.

If the service end point is HTTP, it gives error:

```
System.ArgumentException : The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via
```

Can someone let me know how to Configure WCF so that it send Kerboros token with HTTP URI.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Refer this link. It will be helpful. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to use HTTPS you must set your security mode to `WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly`. If you use `WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport` it demands HTTPS.